# SQL query with listview

Tags: android, listview, azure-sql-database

I am busy with an application where i am getting data from my azure database with sql and storing it in an array. I created a separate class where i get my data and my main activity connects to this class and then displays it.
Here is my getData class:

```
public class GetData {
    Connection connect;
    String ConnectionResult = "";
    Boolean isSuccess = false;

    public List<Map<String,String>> doInBackground() {

        List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        try {
            ConnectionHelper conStr=new ConnectionHelper();
            connect =conStr.connectionclass();        // Connect to database
            if (connect == null) {
                ConnectionResult = "Check Your Internet Access!";
            } else {
                // Change below query according to your own database.
                String query = "select * from cc_rail";
                Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                while (rs.next()) {
                    Map<String,String> datanum=new HashMap<String,String>();
                    datanum.put("NAME",rs.getString("RAIL_NAME"));

                    datanum.put("PRICE",rs.getString("RAIL_UNIT_PRICE"));

                    datanum.put("RANGE",rs.getString("RAIL_RANGE"));

                    datanum.put("SUPPLIER",rs.getString("RAIL_SUPPLIER"));

                    datanum.put("SIZE",rs.getString("RAIL_SIZE"));
                    data.add(datanum);
                }

                ConnectionResult = " successful";
                isSuccess=true;
                connect.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            isSuccess = false;
            ConnectionResult = ex.getMessage();
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

And in my `Fragmentactivity.java` I simply just call the class as shown here:

```
List<Map<String,String>> MyData = null;
GetValence mydata =new GetValence();
MyData= mydata.doInBackground();
String[] fromwhere = { "NAME","PRICE","RANGE","SUPPLIER","SIZE" };

int[] viewswhere = {R.id.Name_txtView , R.id.price_txtView,R.id.Range_txtView,R.id.size_txtView,R.id.supplier_txtView};

ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), MyData,R.layout.list_valence, fromwhere, viewswhere);

list.setAdapter(ADAhere);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        HashMap<String,Object> obj=(HashMap<String,Object>)ADAhere.getItem(position);
        String ID=(String)obj.get("A");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

My problem comes when I want to include the `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` because I am relatively new to android studio and I do not know where to put the following lines of code:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()  {
    ProgressDialog progress;
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Synchronising", "Listview Loading! Please Wait...", true);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
    progress.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the data from your azure database using a background service or `AsyncTask`. However, you are defining a class `GetData` which does not extend `AsyncTask` and hence the whole operation is not asynchronous. And I saw you have implemented `doInBackground` method which is not applicable here as you are not extending `AsyncTask`. I would suggest an implementation like the following.

You want to get some data from your azure database and want to show them in your application. In these kind of situations, you need to do this using an `AsyncTask` to call the server api to get the data and pass the data to the calling activity using an `interface`. Let us have an `interface` like the following.

```
public interface HttpResponseListener {
    void httpResponseReceiver(String result);
}
```

Now from your `Activity` while you want to get the data through an web service call, i.e. `AsyncTask`, just the pass the interface from the activity class to the `AsyncTask`. Remember that your `AsyncTask` should have an instance variable of that listener as well. So the overall implementation should look like the following.

```
public abstract class HttpRequestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    public HttpResponseListener mHttpResponseListener;
    private final Context mContext;

    HttpRequestAsyncTask(Context mContext, HttpResponseListener listener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mHttpResponseListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result = null;

        try {
            // Your implementation of getting data from your server
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        mHttpResponseListener.httpResponseReceiver(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mHttpResponseListener.httpResponseReceiver(null);
    }
}
```

Now you need to have the `httpResponseReceiver` function implemented in the calling `Activity`. So the sample activity should look like.

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HttpResponseListener {
    // ... Other code and overriden functions 

    public void callAsyncTaskForGettingData() {
        // Pass the listener here
        HttpRequestAsyncTask getDataTask = new HttpRequestGetAsyncTask(
            YourActivity.this, this);
        getDataTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void httpResponseReceiver(String result) {
        // Get the response callback here
        // Do your changes in UI elements here. 
    }
}
```

To read more about how to use `AsyncTask`, you might consider having a look at [here](https://medium.com/@JasonCromer/android-asynctask-http-request-tutorial-6b429d833e28).